# Tracking files copied in a directory

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a script that will track when something is copied to directory 'A' and then copy that to a folder we have that is used to move the files to a private network.  I'll call that directory 'b'.  On the other end I have a script that takes those files in 'b' and copies it to a folder that mirrors the other folder on the public network, folder 'c'.  I only want to get those files that have been recently copied into folder 'a'.  The problem is there's no property in the file that track copy dates.  So I figured I would use a text file to track it.  I wrote this script below but it doesn't work.  I think its because when i extract the info from the text file it is no longer an object?  Anyway, any help you can give would be much appreciated.

```
$binaries = "\\network\home\binaries" 
$owt = "\\server1\owt\binaries"

function Get-Directories ($path)
{
    $PathLength = $path.length
        Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse | % {
        Add-Member -InputObject $_ -MemberType NoteProperty -Name RelativePath -Value $_.FullName.substring($PathLength+1)
    $_
}
}
$A= [IO.File]::ReadAllText("\\network\home\binaries\log\log.txt")
$B= Get-Directories $binaries 

#$stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "\\network\home\binaries\log\log.txt" | %   {$stream.WriteLine($b)}
#$stream.close() 
Compare-Object $A $B -Property RelativePath, Name, Length |
Sort RelativePath, Name, Length -desc | % {
if ($file -ne $_.RelativePath) { $_ } } | 
Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "=>"} | 
ForEach-Object {
    $file = $_.RelativePath
    Echo F | xcopy "$binaries\$file" "$owt\$file" /S
}
$c= Get-Directories $binaries | % { $c >> "\\network\home\binaries\log\log.txt"}
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to schedule a shell script that runs robocopy. Robocopy has all kinds of convenient features (mirror, bandwidth throttle, restart on error, and more) that would seem to be better suited to your scenario.

Bill

Answer (score 0):

You could write a script using the [FileSystemWatcher](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b), then start it as a service with [srvany](http://gfdsa.gfdsa.org/2009/11/start-powershell-script-as-service/).